# Error VideoCapture in Phonegap Android App

Tags: android, cordova, video-capture

I am trying to capture video in android app using phonegap, but facing problem

> TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.device.capture.captureVideo' [undefined] is not a function.

Here bellow is my code
 
I included following in head

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function recordVideo(){
 var capture = navigator.device.capture;
 var options1 = { limit: 1 };
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, options1);
alert("Record");
 }

function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {

       alert(mediaFiles[i].name);
    }       
}

function captureError(error) {
    var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;

    alert(msg);
}
</script>
```

And code for capturing on a button click `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="recordVideo();">Capture Video</a>`

But I getting this error on console

> TypeError: Result of expression 'navigator.device.capture.captureVideo' [undefined] is not a function.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Timir

Comment: Are you getting the deviceready event? Do other PhoneGap commands work?

Comment: yes i am getting deviceready event and it is working

Comment: Please can any one help me regarding the above issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the required plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/blob/master/doc/index.md)

If you are using intel xdk go to project -> plugins and permissions